# SQL Syntax column with Accented Characters "é"

Tags: talend

I have a SQL Query with a column which has an Accented Characters "é":

```
SELECT SOINS.NoDossier,
SOINS.Date,
SOINS.Praticien,
SOINS."LibelléCourt",
SOINS.SiteRat
FROM SOINS
```

When I run in the SQL builder it's ok, but when I run my Job I have this error message:

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4034
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tDBInput_11
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][Simba ODBC Driver]Invalid column name: 'LibelléCourt'.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at entrepot_umf06.import_data_production_jde_0_4.Import_data_production_JDE.tDBInput_11Process(Import_data_production_JDE.java:958)
[statistics] disconnected
at entrepot_umf06.import_data_production_jde_0_4.Import_data_production_JDE.runJobInTOS(Import_data_production_JDE.java:1627)
at entrepot_umf06.import_data_production_jde_0_4.Import_data_production_JDE.main(Import_data_production_JDE.java:1461)
Job Import_data_production_JDE terminé à 17:29 04/06/2013. [Code sortie=1]
```

Comment: Have you tried simple quotes instead of double quotes ? When you switch to the "code" view, do you see any errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try like below,

```
SELECT SOINS.NoDossier,
SOINS.Date,
SOINS.Praticien,
SOINS.[LibelléCourt],
SOINS.SiteRat
FROM SOINS
```

SOINS.[LibelléCourt] this will solve your problem.